# Testing rest client in a abstract class directly, using Mockito

Tags: java, spring

I have an abstract class in which I have a method called getInfo that uses restTemplate.exchange. I want to test method directly using Mockito without creating another concrete class to test this method. However, I am getting the null pointer exception when trying to do so.

When I used the same code to test the same rest client code in a concrete class, it works fine.

Below is the abstract class:

```
    public abstract class classToBeTested{

            @Autowired
            private RestTemplate restTemplate;

            protected Response methodToBeTested(){

                String url = "https://example.com";

                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

                ResponseEntity<ClaimsResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Response.class);
                return response;
            }
      }


 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class Test{

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Test
    public void testMethod(){

        String url = "https://example.com";

        classToBeTested service = Mockito.mock(classToBeTested.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

        Response res = new Response();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<Response> response = new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);

        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Response.class)).thenReturn(response);

        Response result = service.methodToBeTested();
        Assert.assertEquals("should be equal", res, result);
     }


}
```

This test should pass but I am getting null pointer exception on the line below:

```
    ResponseEntity<ClaimsResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Response.class)
```

Comment: Your setup will be easier if you use constructor injection instead of field injection and use the `RestOperations` interface instead of the concrete `RestTemplate` implementation.

Comment: Since you are using spring's autowired annotation, shouldn't you be getting the service object from the ApplicationContext, rather than mocking it. For the current situation, since you are mocking the classToBeTested and calling real methods, the @Autowired annotation is not fired, as Spring's application context is never loaded, so the restTemplate remains uninitialized. This gives you the NullPointerException.